# Gradle From Terminal Using Wrong JDK Version

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, gradle

I have a Spring Boot project that I just migrated from Spring Boot 2.7 to 3.2, and I also had to change it from JDK 11 to JDK 17. It builds and runs fine within Intellj IDEA.

When I go to the terminal and run `./gradlew build` to get an executable jar, it fails to build and looks like it's trying to use JDK 11 still, and also an older Kotlin version.

> > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.2.2.
> > Required by:
> > project : > org.springframework.boot:org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin:3.2.2
> > > No matching variant of org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:3.2.2 was found.   The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 11, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribu
> > te 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.4.1' but:

`./gradlew --version` outputs:

> Kotlin:       1.5.31
> Groovy:       3.0.9
> Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
> JVM:          11.0.13 (JetBrains s.r.o. 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866)

Where is it getting these old versions from? Kotlin is 1.9.22 in my build.gradle, and Java Version is 17.

Comment: Have you tried jvmToolchain in your gradle file? It can be used to better control which JVM is used to execute gradle, to compile your code and so on.

Comment: Yes, I put `kotlin {
 jvmToolchain(17)
}` in my gradle file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle will try to find the java executable under `JAVA_HOME` folder and use it if it exists. If not exist, it will try to use the default `java` command. So either your `JAVA_HOME` is pointing to a java version 11 folder or your default `java` in cmd is using java 11. Try using `update-java-alternatives` command to point `java` command to java 17.

Comment: I fixed it by editing my PATH environment variable, thanks!